# PostgreSQL + Hibernate + C3P0 = FATAL: sorry, too many clients already

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, c3p0

I have the following code

```
    Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
    config.buildMappings();
    serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry(); 
    SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    Session hibernateSession = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = hibernateSession.beginTransaction();
    ObjectType ot = (ObjectType)hibernateSession.merge(someObj);
    tx.commit();
    return ot;
```

`hibernate.cfg.xml` contains:

```
<session-factory>

    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/dbase</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>

    <property name="connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property>

    <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>        
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay">250</property>

    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <mapping class="...." />

</session-factory>
```

After a few seconds and some successful inserts, the following exception appears:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:291)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
12:24:19.151 [          Thread-160] WARN                   internal.JdbcServicesImpl - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
12:24:19.151 [          Thread-160] INFO                             dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
12:24:19.151 [          Thread-160] INFO                  internal.LobCreatorBuilder - HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
12:24:19.151 [          Thread-160] INFO        internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator - HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
12:24:19.151 [          Thread-160] INFO               ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
12:24:19.151 [          Thread-160] INFO                        hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
12:24:19.151 [          Thread-160] INFO                        hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
12:24:19.211 [Runner$PoolThread-#0] WARN              resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@ee4084 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (1). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:291)
```

It seems that the hibernate doesn't realse the connection. But `hibernateSession.close()` causes exception `Session is closed` because `tx.commit()` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause why c3p0 behaved in this way.The issue was quite trivial...
This part of code:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
config.buildMappings();
serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry(); 
SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

was executed multiple times. Thank you Steve for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what's going on here, but I'd recommend you not set hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts to 1. First, that renders your next setting, hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay irrelevant -- that sets the length of time between retry attempts, but if there is only one attempt (ok, the param name is misleading, it sets the total number of tries), there are no retries. The effect of your settings is simply to have the pool try to fetch a Connection whenever a client comes in, then throw an Exception to clients immediately if that fails. It doesn't at all limit the number of Connections the pool will try to acquire (unless you set breakOnAcquireFailure to true, in which case, with your settings, any failure to acquire a Connection would invalidate the whole pool).

I share sola's concern about your lack of reliable resource cleanup. If, under your settings, commit() means close() (and you are not allowed to call close explicitly? that seems bad), then it is commit that should be in the finally block (but commit in a finally block also seems bad, sometimes you don't want to commit). Whatever the issue with close/commit, with the code you have, occasional Exceptions between openSession and commit will lead to Connection leaks.

But that should not be the cause of your too-many-open-Connections problem. If you leak Connections, you'll find that the Connection pool eventually freezes (as maxPoolSize Connectiosn are checked out forever due to the leaks). You'd only have 25 open Connections. Something else is going on. Try reviewing your logs. Is more than one Connection pool somehow being initialized? (c3p0 dumps config information at INFO level on pool init, so if multiple pools are getting opened, you should see multiple messages. alternatively, you can inspect running c3p0 pools via JMX, to see whether/why more than 25 Connections have been opened.)

Good luck!

Comment: You are right. c3p0 initialises pool 41 times and shows the message `Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@f3dc5b64 [ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@a959e809 [ acquireIncrement -> 1, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl...`. This version is shorten because it is too long. What could be the cause?

Comment: Well, c3p0 isn't doing it autonomously. I'd guess that either something in your set-up is causing many c3p0 DataSources to be instantiated, or else you are hitting the pool with many different user/password pairs. (c3p0 creates a separate pool for every user/password pair requested of it.)

Comment: I anticipated this kind of answer :) I have to find the cause. Point for you and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggesting you to use  `try-catch-finally`   block,

in  `finally`  kindly close the session

i.e

```
try {           
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        handleException(e);
    } finally {
        hibernateSession.close();
    }
```

and also,
the   `max_connections`   property in postgresql.conf it's 100 by default. Increase it if you need.

Comment: As I wrote in my question, calling `hibernateSession.close()` causes `Exception in thread "Thread-18" org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!`. `tx.commit()` already has closed the session. Increasing `max_connections` to 200 (and restart) nothing changes :( I changed also `<property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>` from deprecated `org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider`.